# Packing theme into a distribution in drupal

Tags: drupal-7, migration

I am using a drupal community theme, slightly customized as per requirement. I am facing problems when I am porting the theme with a distribution.
On installation that distribution does not load the custom theme, but downloads the theme from drupal community.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use **Drush** for that because Drush will fetch the files (modules, themes etc) from the online repositories.

Just follow the **normal installation method**. Download the installation profile, override the theme folder with your customized theme folder and then run the install.php through browser.

Comment: Yes I am following the same procedure. The issue is I have a community theme and Added a custom region, but when I install the profile the custom region is lost.

Comment: Same procedure is through Drush?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The entire procedure is through drush.

Comment: So use the normal installation method through browser with install.php. Drush is fetching the drupal projects from their repositories.

Comment: Yes exactly. So what I want is Drush not to fetch the theme from the repositories. Instead load my custom theme with added regions.

Comment: You should probable read carefully the manuals for [drush](http://drush.ws/#site-install), [installation profiles](https://drupal.org/node/1085382) and [.make files](http://drush.ws/docs/make.txt) so you have a clear opinion about how .make files work. Otherwise you should replace the theme folder with your customized one and then install as usual through browser.

Comment: I think the latter option is better as I am using the community theme with added regions (slight customization).

Comment: @AnandS.Bahuguna Did my answer solve your problem? If so please give some positive feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).